# C# XML in listbox. How to get which item is selected?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, listbox

I have an xml of books. When new books are added to this xml, they get a number. Each book has different number. The user can select a book by clicking on it on a listbox. Then the user can click on a button to change the selected book's informations. A new form shows, but I can't pass the information which book has to be changed. (This information would be the number.)

```
private int GetNumber()
{

    foreach (var book in xmlofbooks.Descendants("Book"))
    {
        if (book.Attribute("Number")==listbox1.SelectedItem
    }


    return ;
}
```

Comment: i guess your selected item must be a book and not some number.is tht rt?

Comment: The selected item is the book with all its informations. But I only need the 'number'.

Comment: book.Attribute("Number").Value will do that

Comment: Yes, but how to get the number value of the selected one in the listbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not create a simple Book class, deserialize your XML into `List<Book>` and bind it to the `ListBox`. You can then set `DisplayMember` to the Title (or whatever you want displayed) and the `ValueMember` to the Number. You can retrieve the number with `MyListBox.SelectedValue` and pass it to whatever needs it. Set the datasource as such: `MyListBox.DataSource = MyListOfBooks;`

You may be able to bind that information to the XML directly, but I have no idea how.

Answer (score 1):

For this particular type of workings with XML data, you could learn XML Serialization / Deserialization. This will allow you to Deserialize your XML Data into a IEnumerable Class Object.

Once you have the XML in this state then using it as a Datasource for Form Controls becomes way easier to manage.

Here's an example :-

http://www.developerfusion.com/code/2517/serialize-and-deserialize-objects-to-an-xml-file/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to compare value of attribute with content of item:

```
if (book.Attribute("Number").Value.Equals(listbox1.SelectedItem.Content))
{
    // ...
}
```